# YouTube channelid, channel title and googlePlusUserId relatedness

Tags: youtube-api

In v3 API each logged user may have a number of channels each one with a specific `channelId`. Moreover, I know that the channel title is not unique. My goal is the group the channels that belong to specific YouTube users if that possible. So:

1. Is `googlePlusUserId` identify the person that has a sequence of channels? In other words can we use `googlePlusUserId` to group channels that belong to a YouTube user?
2. If yes, is `googlePlusUserId` available to all YouTube channels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is googlePlusUserId identify the person that has a sequence of channels? In other words can we use googlePlusUserId to group channels
>      that belong to a YouTube user?

Nop, the `googlePlusId` identify the GG+ of the channel. It can be a **Google+ page** or **Google+ identity.**

Each channel have a differents Google+ id.
You can read more about [YouTube and Google+ id](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html)